# What is the funciton of the particle ぞ, and does it have any other uses?

Tags: particles

I've only heard it - with its apparent use in this case - in phrases about knowledge specific to someone or something, as in:

> かみのみぞしるあめのみぞしる。

I would normally - with my low-level understanding of Japanese - use を and say for example:

> それはかみのみをしること。

I've not found any info on Google. What is the function of ぞ and where else can it be used?

Comment: Here is a related post: [Which part of speech is the 「ぞ」 in 「神のみぞ知るセカイ」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/170/) . I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody *uses* it now, because it is a piece of grammar from classical Japanese. The final particle ぞ is a descendant of it, and otherwise only remains in sporadic idioms: ～のみぞ知る, どうぞ, これぞ, よくぞ, 何するものぞ etc.

By the way, its meaning is not related to を. In old Japanese they don't have consistent nominative or accusative markers, so it could be a subject or an object.

> かみのみぞしる
> *It is only god(s) that knows.*